# PHP - string filtering (regex?)

Tags: php, regex, string

I have multiple PHP strings (10-100k characters each) and want to get exact elements with their children from them.

Example:

```
$bbc_string = file_get_contents('http://www.bbc.co.uk/');
echo $bbc_string;
```

Gives 90544 characters and displays the whole page. But who needs the whole page, including navigation, footer etc.?

What if I want to display only, let's say:

```
<div id="news_container">
   everything in it
</div>
```

Or:

```
<h2 id="worldService_title">
   everything in it
</h2>
```

How to filter or parse $bbc_string output to show what I want?

I think regex is the solution, I've found this pattern:

```
preg_match('/<div id=\"".$id."\">(.*?)</div>/', $string, $matches);
```

But it doesn't work and is supposed to work only for divs not all elements.

Any PHP/regex ninjas around?

Comment: Parseing HTML with PHP has been asked/answered here so many times I'm not even going to be bother looking up the duplicates - flat out vote to close.

Comment: How about using some xml/dom parser that will parse the structure for you and you only access object trees?

Comment: @Marc B, sorry, haven't found any clear answers on this topic.

Comment: XPath: `//div[@id="worldService_title"]`

Comment: @Wordpressor: Word of warning: There is a large (majority) cult here at stackoverflow who have all concluded that it is impossible to parse HTML with regular expressions. Their belief in this notion is absolute and unbending. So beware that anytime you breath the words: "REGEX" and "HTML" in the same sentence, you will get an automatic and immediate knee-jerk reaction saying: "Don't do it!" (Even if regex may be the best tool for the specific problem at hand.) They will frequently shut down a thread such as this one. Don't take it personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse HTML.